# Route traffic on datacenters without traffic usage

Tags: routing, route

Imagine you have 2 servers, one on OVH and another one on Hetzner and each of them has a 500GB traffic usage limit.

can you route traffic from Hetzner to OVH without traffic usage for Hetzner?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Buy more traffic to increase your quota.

Like many rent-a-server providers [Hetzner bills for outgoing traffic](https://docs.hetzner.com/cloud/billing/faq/#how-do-you-bill-for-traffic). Covers some of their costs, and provides an incentive to stay hosting with them. Any egress of their network, so yes getting to another provider via the internet would be billable. Ask Hetzner about the details.

If you were to acquire your own IP transit, may be able to [peer with them](https://www.peeringdb.com/net/1766) and negotiate.  Expensive, but at some point paying for dedicated links may become a better value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I live in Iran and Iran blocked Iranians access to global Internet and we can only access to servers that hosted in Iran datacenters, someone told me we can do routing with an Iran VPS to bypass that, do you know how can we do that? I asked him how, but he don't answer me :(